# Transponer filas a columnas mysql

Tags: mysql

Buen día, tengo un problema con una una consulta en mysql, tengo una tabla de registro de asistencia la cual tiene los campos id, empleado, fechahorareg, status. En esta tabla se diferencia la entrada y salida por el status (1 = entrada, 2= salida), pero al hacer una simple consulta, tengo dos registros para un día, lo cual quiero poner las dato de entrada en una columna el de salida en otra, pero en una sola fila.
Algo como:
idempleado   regentrada   regsalida

```
CREATE TABLE `tbregistros`(
`idregistros` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`idempleado` int NOT NULL, 
`fechahorareg` datetime NOT NULL, 
`status` int(1) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`idregistros`) USING BTREE,)
```

Al hacer una simple consulta.

```
SELECT * FROM tbregistros WHERE idempleado = 1
```

el resultado es:

```
Idregistros idempleado  Fechahorareg         status  
1           1           2021-01-01 08:23:04  1
2           1           2021-01-01 18:40:04  2
3           1           2021-01-02 08:23:04  1
4           1           2021-01-02 18:40:04  2
```

Al hacer la consulta con CASE:

```
SELECT idempleado, 
`status`, 
CASE WHEN `status` = 1 THEN fechahorareg ELSE NULL END AS horaentrada, 
CASE WHEN `status` = 2 THEN fechahorareg ELSE NULL END AS horasalida
FROM tbregistros 
WHERE idempleado = 1
```

el resultado es:

```
Idempleado  status  horaentrada          horasalida 
1           1       2021-01-01 08:23:04  NULL
1           2       NULL                 2021-01-01 18:40:04
1           1       2021-01-02 08:23:04  NULL
1           2       NULL                 2021-01-02 18:40:04
```

El resultado que busco es:

```
Idempleado  status  horaentrada           horasalida 
1           1       2021-01-01 08:23:04   2021-01-01 18:40:04 
1           2       2021-01-02 08:23:04   2021-01-02 18:40:04
```

Comment: El problema de tu transposición de la tabla `tbregistros` es el resultado,  te muestra el mismo `status` para la `horaentrada` y `horasalida`, cuando estas tienen `1` y `2` respectivamente.

Comment: si, de echo cuando uso el case

CASE WHEN `status` = 1 THEN fechahorareg ELSE NULL END AS horaentrada, 
CASE WHEN `status` = 2 THEN fechahorareg ELSE NULL END AS horasalida
si valido los dos valores del status, o en que momento debo de indicar??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma de resolverlo, asumiendo que status = 1 corresponde a entrada y status = 2 a salida seria esta:

```
select ent.idempleado, ent.fechahorareg HoraEntrada,  sal.fechahorareg HoraSalida
from
(   select t1.idempleado, t1.fechahorareg, t1.status,
    (
        select COUNT(*) +1
        from tbregistros
        where idempleado = t1.idempleado
        and status = 1
        and idregistros < t1.idregistros
    )  intRow
    from tbregistros t1
    where status = 1
)ent
left join
( 
    select t1.idempleado, t1.fechahorareg, t1.status,
    (
        select COUNT(*) +1
        from tbregistros
        where idempleado = t1.idempleado
        and status = 2
        and idregistros < t1.idregistros
    )  intRow
    from tbregistros t1
    where status = 2
)sal
on ent.intRow = sal.intRow and ent.idempleado = sal.idempleado
```

[Prueba en MySQL 5.5](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=7b12bb4721bf39c9bd6bebbc35f1eb8b)

Comment: Que tal, gracias, esa consulta muestra un error en la sintaxis de sql

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CTE as 
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() over ( order by(select null) )rownum, idempl' at line 1

estoy usando mysql5

Comment: Edite mi respuesta con una versión del script que probé en MySQL 5.5. Únicamente considera que la columna status ya no tiene sentido, porque el concepto de entrada y salida ahora esta representado en las columnas HoraEntrada y HoraSalida.

Comment: Muchas gracias, es exactamente lo que estaba buscando!!!